# Why is xlCalculationAutomatic making my macro hang?

Tags: excel, vba

I've created a  macro in Excel for Office 365 to copy data from a source workbook (Source) into an array and append that array to the end of of table in an analysis workbook (Analysis). The Analysis workbook is fairly formula-heavy, so can take a minute to update when changes are made.

At the beginning of the macro, I use `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` to speed things up and at the end I use `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` to return them to normal.

Excel hung when I tried to run the macro today. It got stuck at the point that it showed "Calculating (4 threads): 50%" until after several minutes I force-closed it. It did this twice, and upon further investigation -- as expected -- I found that it was occurring at the last line in the macro: `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic`.

I commented out that line and ran the macro again with no issues, then used the `F9` key to calculate the sheet and it calculated very quickly.

So my question is: why is the macro hanging when I use `xlCalculationAutomatic` in the code if Excel has no problem doing a full calculation after the macro has run? Is there a way around this?

Here are the last few lines of the code:

```
 ' Paste data; copy and paste formatting
   rngPaste.Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrTemp)
 
   rngTblOldLastRow.Copy
   rngPaste.PasteSpecial xlFormats
 
 NormalMode:
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   'Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
 
 End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe your sheet have more than 10k row, and each row contain formula, so one you turn it back, the re-calculation will lag the sheet. I am facing extreme lag when convert large number row of text to number also.

Comment: Really just a guess - add `Application.CutCopyMode = False` after the last `.Paste`/`.PasteSpecial`, just to clear the clipboard...maybe that's taking up space too?

Answer (score 0):

The entry `xlCalculationAutomatic` makes Excel calculate the result of every individual formula, from the moment that any change to the sheet is made.

E.g. you have an Excel file, containing thousands of formulas, and you have a macro, which modifies or adds hundreds of entries. When you have the mode `xlCalculationAutomatic`, then all thousands of formulas will be executed at every of the hundreds of entries your macro is modifying or adding. Excel does not hang at such a moment, but it might take a lot of time to finish the task.
Without that `xlCalculationAutomatic`, your macro will pause the calculation of the formulas, add or  modify your hundreds of entries and only calculate all formulas once.

Therefore it is advised not to use this mode while you are working with macros, except, of course, when your macro is using formula results.

A more professional explanation can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlcalculation).